# Serve Javascript as text from Firebase Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to serve some text as javascript from a firebase function.

My function looks like:

```
module.exports.js = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let source = "....";
  res.status(200).send(source);
});
```

That I want to be able to load it in a `<script/>` tag:

```
<script type="module" src="https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/js?foo=bar"></script>
```

But when I do, I get an error in the browser:

> TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

I've tried adding a `type("application/javascript")` to the response, with no affect.

How do I set the correct response headers / MIME type so that my response can be loaded by the browser as Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Problem was in the ...'s.

Setting response headers does do the trick:

```
res.set({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
});
```